# unable to communicate wirelessly using arduino and nrf24L01+ transceivers

Tags: arduino

my transceivers are working fine as the codes from maniacbug's RF24 master library is working perfectly.but i tried to learn to program it myself so i decided to send some integers back and forth.they do not seem to work.the serial monitor prints different integer.
the TX code is-

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include"nRF24L01.h"
#include"RF24.h"
//#include"printf.h"
RF24 radio(9,10);
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };
const unsigned int transmit =1995;
//unsigned int get = 1;
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //printf_begin();
  Serial.println("lets begin the operation");
  radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
  radio.setPayloadSize(8);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  //Serial.print("now get is  ");
  //Serial.println(get);
  //radio.startListening();
  //radio.printDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{
      //printf("starting the transmission\n");
      Serial.println("starting the transmission");
      radio.stopListening();
      bool ok = radio.write( &transmit, 8 );
      if(ok)
        //printf("ok....transmission successful !!!");
        Serial.println("ok...transmission successful..!!");
      else
        //printf("faioed to tramsmitt\n");
        Serial.println("failed to transmit");
      radio.startListening();
      unsigned int get;
      bool ok2 = radio.read( &get, 8);
      if(ok2)
      {
        //printf("received the packet successfully\n");
        Serial.println("received the packet successfully");
        //printf("received package is %u\n",get);
        Serial.print("received package is  ");
        Serial.println(get);
      }
      else
        //printf("failed to receive\n");
        Serial.println("failed to receive");
        delay(1000);
}
```

the RX code is-

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include"nRF24L01.h"
#include"RF24.h"
//#include"printf.h"
RF24 radio(9,10);
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };
unsigned int transmit = 2014;
//unsigned int get = 0;
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //printf_begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
  radio.setPayloadSize(8);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
  //radio.startListening();
  //radio.printDetails();
}
void loop(void)
{
  radio.startListening();
  unsigned int get;
  bool ok = radio.read(&get,8);
  if(ok)
  {
    //printf("received successfully\n");
    Serial.println("received successfully");
    //printf("received payload = %u\n",get);
    Serial.print("received payload is  ");
    Serial.println(get);
  }
  else
    //printf("failed to receive\n");
    Serial.println("failed to receive");
  radio.stopListening();
  //unsigned int transmit = 2014;
  bool ok2 = radio.write( &transmit,8 );
  if(ok)
    //printf("ok....transmission successful !!!");
    Serial.println("ok...transmission successful..!!");
  else
    //printf("faioed to tramsmitt\n");
    Serial.println("failed to transmit");
  delay(1000);

}
```

even the printf.h header file does not seem to work when i write the code but they work just fine in the library examples.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Baud rate of the serial window and mostly 9600 baud creates problem. Try checking 57600 Baud rate

Comment: i changed my code a bit and it started working well with baud rate at 57600